# Execute function only once for user idle timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display offer banner when the user idle timeout 5 seconds, however following code is showing offer banner every idle 5 seconds.But i want execute the following function only once for first idle 5 seconds.Any body help me out

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           idleTime = 0;        


           //Increment the idle time counter every five second.
           var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 5000);

           function timerIncrement()
           {
             console.log(idleTime++);
             if (idleTime > 5)
             {
               doPreload();     

             }
           }

           //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
           $(this).mousemove(function(e){

                 idleTime = 0;

           });

           function doPreload()
           {
             $('#add-click').click();

           }   

        });
```

Comment: move the if (idle... ) inside the doPreload.. I think you cannot check the idleTime variable inside the timer because the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        timerIncrement();
}, 5000);
```

This will execute only once.

Comment: could you create a JSFiddle or plunkr so that i can check.

Comment: wait i will add and let u know

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Checking now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136241/discussion-between-aka-and-nageswar).

Answer (score 2):

you are using only mouse move what if the user working with keyboard you have to check for that also

```
var inactivityTime = function () {
var temp;
window.onload = resetTimer;
document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(temp);
    temp = setTimeout(logout, 3000)
    // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: i can't comment , need 50 rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct the logic in this function as :

```
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
  function timerIncrement() {
    console.log(idleTime++);
    if (idleTime == 5) {
        doPreload();
        idleTime = 0;   // reset idleTime variable     
      }
  }

   /** This will increase counter by one every second,
    *  and if counter reaches to 5 then call to banner
    *  display and reset counter. 
    */
```